# how do I count 1st column values against the second value(in which 1 st column values are repeated)

Tags: sql

[how do I count the number of times p's value is repeated in  column n ]

[image: 1]

Comment: please provide desired output in text

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

If I Understand what you want, you can use this code :

This Code is to create your sample data:

```
SELECT  1  AS N, 2 AS P INTO #t
UNION ALL
SELECT  3  AS N, 2 AS P
UNION ALL
SELECT  6  AS N, 8 AS P
UNION ALL
SELECT  9  AS N, 8 AS P
UNION ALL
SELECT  2  AS N, 5 AS P
UNION ALL
SELECT  8  AS N, 5 AS P
UNION ALL
SELECT  8  AS N, NULL AS P
```

Here is the code to count column

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #t t WHERE t.N = #t.p) AS c  FROM #t

DROP TABLE #t
```